# Creating a Yes/No modal dialog box

Tags: development, 2007

Apologies if this is a pretty basic question but I'm a relative SharePoint newbie and I've been trying to find an answer for this for a couple of days.

I have an SPToolBarButton that provide Delete functionality via its OnClick. However, I need to prompt the users with an 'Are you sure?' Yes/No modal dialog box.

I have attempted to use OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" but can't find a way of picking up the user's selection from within my code-behind page.

Is this even the correct approach to use?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2):

If the user [clicks "Cancel" in the confirm then it will return false and the postback cancelled](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=93).

Since there is no postback then the code-behind doesn't actually run - so no check of which button clicked is needed.